# MongoDB permite ejecutar comandos sin estar autenticado

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, autenticación, nosql, users-roles

Me estoy iniciando con el sistema de base de datos de MongoDB y me estoy encontrando una serie de problemas relacionados con la autenticación y seguridad.

Con el fin de conseguir un sistema seguro estoy intentando habilitar el control de usuarios y autenticación en el sistema, para ello lo primero que he realizado, ha sido crear el usuario administrador sobre la base de datos "admin" tal y como se especifica en la documentación oficial.

```
db.createUser({
user: "admin",
pwd: "admin",
roles: [
    {
        role: "userAdminAnyDatabase",
        db: "admin"
    },
    "readWriteAnyDatabase"
], });
```

Una vez creado, he añadido la propiedad de seguridad correspondiente en el fichero de configuración (**mongod.cfg**) como activa.

```
security: authorization: enabled
```

Por ultimo he reiniciado mi servicio y el problema lo he encontrado al comprobar el correcto funcionamiento. Ya que al iniciar la shell correspondiente, me permite realizar acciones como ver las bases de datos del sistema, crear nuevas, insertar datos... y todo esto sin llegar a estar logueado.

¿Alguien sabe porque razón puede estar sucediendo esto?¿Debo de configurar algo más? Por mas que busco y pruebo posibles soluciones no logro resolver el problema.

Muchas gracias.

PD: Estoy trabajando bajo Windows

Comment: Sobre que SO estas corriendo mongo?

Comment: ¿Te has 'situado' en la base de datos admin (mediante use admin) antes de crear el usuario?